# Axes font needs to not be bold

Tags: html, css

I have the following live demo: [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/MmvSzJyZ2fTT58Oofu5j?p=preview)

I'd like to:
1. Keep the axes tick marks
2. Keep the axes labels
3. Leave the axes lines hidden

How do I change the font of the axes labels so they are *not bold* ?

This I think is the section of the `css` that is getting confused:

```
.xAxis {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 8px;
    font-weight: 200; 
    fill: black;
}

.xAxis text {
    font: 8pt Verdana;
    fill: black;
}

.yAxis {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 8px;
    font-weight: 200; 
    fill: black;
    /*shape-rendering: crispEdges;*/
}

.yAxis text {
    font: 8pt Verdana;
    fill: black;
}

.tick {
    stroke: black;
    fill: black;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.domain {
    fill: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add stroke: none; to yout .xAxis text-Definition like so:

```
.xAxis text {
    font: 8pt Verdana;
    stroke: none;
    fill: black;
}
```

You are not actually making the text bold here (like font-weight: bold;) but instead drawing a line around it. Thats also the reason why your text is so blurry, using strokes on (small) text elements is not a good idea in most cases.